# Troubleshooting Notation Package

Tags: custom-notation

I would like to switch some mathematica functions (and variables) to forms that are more readable. I am hoping simply to change some notation for derivatives and make it so that I can symbolize subscripted variables. I've read online about using the "Notation Package," but I haven't had any luck getting it to work. I'm not sure if this is because I am making a simple mistake or if the resources I'm using only work for an older version of Mathematica.

When I run this code:

```
<< Notation`

Notation[
        ParsedBoxWrapper[
            RowBox[{FractionBox["df_", "dx_"], " "}]] 
       \[DoubleLongRightArrow] 
         ParsedBoxWrapper[
            RowBox[{"D", "[", 
            RowBox[{"f_", ",", "x_"}], "]"}]]]
         Notation[ParsedBoxWrapper[
            RowBox[{FractionBox[
            RowBox[{
         SuperscriptBox["d", "n_"], "f_"}], 
         SuperscriptBox["dx_", "n_"]], " "}]] 
      \[DoubleLongRightArrow] 
         ParsedBoxWrapper[
            RowBox[{"D", "[", 
            RowBox[{"f_", ",", 
            RowBox[{"{", RowBox[{"x_", ",", "n_"}], "}"}]}], "]"}]]]
```

(as a side note: this is what appears when I paste after I copy the mathematica code in the tutorial. I'm suprised how much a mess all of this code is. Is it worth my time to go through this code or should I just stick to copy+pasting the formatted code in the tutorial?)

Some difficulties I've encountered:

Running the above code throws:

```
"Notation::inpatnf: "Pattern 'f' appearing in the internal representation    
\'\!\(Notation`Private`identityForm[RowBox[{\"D\", \"[\", RowBox[{\"f_\
\", \",\", \"x_\"}], \"]\"}]]\)' cannot be filled since 'f' does not \
appear in the external representation 'Notation`Private`identityForm[\
\!\(RowBox[{FractionBox[\"df_\", \"dx_\"], \" \"}]\)]'""
```

Comment: Not really answering your question, but from my own experience I can say that any attempts using subscripted variables in *Mathematica* are most likely not worth the effort. There are ways to write clean code, but it will look different than your LaTeX document.

Comment: You need to add a space between `d` and `f_` in `df_` to make it `d f_`, similarly change `dx_` to `d x_`. This is what `Notation::inpatnf` warning is telling, you have `f` pattern on RHS but it's not present on LHS, since on LHS you have pattern named `df`.

Comment: *Mathematica* has special [`\[DifferentialD]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/character/DifferentialD.html) and [`\[PartialD]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/character/PartialD.html) characters, so we don't have to confuse `d` symbol with symbols related to derivatives. In "Typesetting" section of "Basic Math", "Classroom" and "Writing" assistants you can find templates for derivatives in "fractional forms", that are interpreted correctly in `TraditionalForm` input.